# Multiple table inner join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables defined as follows:

```
merchant (name: string, price: integer) 
finance (no: string, gname: string, minCredit: integer) 
borrower (dname: string, gno: string, deliverydate: date)
```

example data set:

```
merchant |  finance |
ally s      jumbo
jim b       jumbo
jimmy g     small
```

borrower.dname and borrower.gno are foreign keys referencing merchant.name and finance.no

I am trying to write a query to find finances which have a strictly great number of borrowers than the average number of  borrowers over all finance types. I am trying to output the finance number (no.)

What I have tried:

```
 select f.no as no
 from borrower b
 join merchant m on m.name = b.dname
 join finance f on f.no = b.gno
 where count(m.name) > avg(b.dname)
```

This does not seem to give me the correct result. I think I am on the right path with joining the table and I believe my problem is with the where statement(?)  Any help to put me on the right path?

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH findata AS 
(SELECT
    f.no
    ,COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM
    finance f
GROUP BY 
    f.no)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    findata
WHERE 
     Cnt > (SELECT AVG(Cnt) FROM findata)
```

Comment: The `;` needs to go at the end of the statement, not the beginning

Comment: In addition to what @a_horse_with_no_name said, not onlt the `;` is **misplaced**. It's also **competely optional** and can be removed, since is really **not needed** at all.